# Find Exponent of Power

Tags: math

If I call (passing in dValue):

```
dBase := 1.4; (constant)
dRes := Power(dBase, dValue);
```

Where Power is defined as function Power(const Base, Exponent: Double): Double;

Now given that I now know dRes and dbase (1.4), how can I calculate the exponent, dValue?

Thanks

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: `z = x^y` ==> `ln(z)=ln(x^y) = y*ln(x)` ==> `y = ln(z)/ln(x)`

Comment: Hm, that looks Pascal-ish to me. Not that that makes it any clearer what you're asking. Are you actually asking "what is the mathematical operation for doing this?"

Comment: It's called a logarithm.

Comment: Thanks guys. Mathematics was a l-o-n-g time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(z) = ln(x^y)
```

Now by the power property of logarithms:

```
ln(z) = y * ln(x)
```

Now just divide

```
y = ln(z)/ln(x)
```

or in your case:

```
dValue = ln(dRes)/ln(dBase)
```